# Open/closed hand recognition: a simple method

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, image-recognition

I'm searching for a simple method to recognize if an hand is open or closed.

I'm using C# and [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), but this is not significative in this context. I only need a "pseudo-code" that describes what I need to do.

The input image to this algorithm is a binary image (I've already implemented the segmentation process) that represents the hand. The output must be a boolean (true for open hand, false otherwise).

This is an input example:

[image]

I tried to consider something about the convex hull, or the percentage of white area, but I guess these methods are not robust enough for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In machine learning terms what you are trying to do is classification on a binary input matrix of the size of your input image (1 for white pixel, 0 for black pixel), to a single binary output (1 for open hand, 0 for closed hand).

If you build up a training set by taking lots of images of closed and open hands and hand label them (pun not intended), than you can apply a supervised learning algorithm to create the classifier.

There are many choices for supervised learning algorithms.  Perhaps the best one to try for a first shot would be a support vector machine:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine

Support vector machines work by essentially calculating the "distance" between the input image and the examples provided in the training set.  If the input image is "closer" on average to the examples of open hands from the training set than the closed hands from the training set, it will classify it as an open hand (and visa versa).

There are many other supervised learning algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning

Comment: I didn't experience the concept of Support Vector Machine, but what you say looks like using a neural network. Am I right?

Comment: @VitoShadow: Support Vector Machines and Neural Networks are related in some ways, but are different algorithms.  You could also use a Neural Network by making the input image the input neuron layer, the single binary output one output neuron and then one or more hidden layers.  You can then train it with backpropogation on the training set.  You will need a much larger training set for a neural net, and it takes longer to train, but will generally get better results if you have a large set and sufficient time.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to train a neural network, and then use it. And because this approach is included in supervised learning, I accept your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @VitoShadow: Your problem is not unlike the problem of classifying handwritten digits (instead of 10 output states you have only two).  If you look on [this page](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) you will see a list of algorithms and their results.

Answer (score 1):

Convex Hull should do good, you can calculate the black area percentage lying in convex hull, and if its greater than some threshold, then hand is open.
Otherwise you can just calculate area & perimeter of the white area, then check their ratio, for open hands area / perimeter should be less than for closed hands.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced about your considerations on Area/Perimeter value. Is that ratio always less for closed hands?

Comment: Closed hand is more similar to circle than open hand, and therefore it has small perimeter compared to its area. Open hand has an extra perimeter because of left/right sides of each finger, i.e. it is more fuzzy. When hand is opened, image area is increased a little, but perimeter is increased much more, and therefore area / perimeter decreases (same as if I'd say that perimeter / area increases).

Comment: This is what is called a "hand-written feature detector".  What you can do is in a preprocessing step calculate this Area/Permiter value on your input matrix, than include the result as another input variable (alongside the image pixels).  If it is a good predictor for certain images than the machine learning algorithm will weight the feature accordingly.  If it isn't it will be regularized out and will be ignored.  In such a way you can simulatenously try out lots of different feature detectors like this in parallel.